# How to work a button inside a fragment

Tags: android, button, sdk, fragment

I have used a fragment (which has two buttons inside), but I do not have to find a way make these buttons work. Have in mind that I use an activity which is connected to the specific fragment.

Do anyone knows a way to make buttons open other buttons in android sdk tool?

Comment: posy some relevant code

Answer (score 4):

This sample will help you. Don't forget to create the layout with button for this fragment

```
    public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button mButton = null;
    public SampleFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_fragment, container, false);
        mButton= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //Do your stuff on button action
                }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple onClickListener on the button that u want to work with.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
```